# Node.JS callback closes websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sockets, socket.io

I have next problem - I need to make a request to Postgresql DB and then send it's result via socket in responce.
The code looks like next:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);     
var pg=require('pg')
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

io.on('connection', function(socket){

 socket.on('give me data',function(data){

                    var query =client.query(" select 1 as data limit 1")

                    query.on('row',function(row){
                        io.sockets.in(address).emit('take your data',row)
                    })
                    query.on('error',function(err){
                        console.log('FRUSTRATING ERROR', err);
                    })
                })
}
```

When pg query starts - socket thought out this error :

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
```

Does anyone know how can this issue be solved?

Comment: Maybe the extra space here? client.query(" select 1 as data limit 1") between (" select?

Comment: Yeah, extra spaces are known for closing all ports and shutting down your PC,...nasty little buggers...

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
io.sockets.in(address).emit('take your data',row)
```

to

```
socket.in(address).emit('take your data',row)
```